# Vanishing Data on Edit in KendoUI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I have an interesting issue cropping up with my KendoUI().Grid.

The grid initially is fine (and operates great on Create, Delete, Cancel, and save methodology). But when I click on a row's Edit button, and the row goes into edit mode, two of my controls "lose" their data. The data doesn't appear in the text boxes. These are Kendo text boxes, with the little up/down arrow dealies to raise and lower the value in the box, and the interesting part is that those still work.

Pictures speak a thousand words, so here's screenshots:
http://paulkahl.smugmug.com/InterJunk/CoderJunk/i-M9X5K8T

They go in order:

1. Load the grid, all looks well.
2. Click the Edit button, grid goes into edit mode, but the data is gone!
3. Click the up/down buttons, and the 'invisible' numbers increment perfectly!
4. Click Update, and the data saves just fine!

The code is pretty slim, really:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project.Model.ViewModel.TheDataDetailViewModel>()
    .DataSource(dataSource =>
        dataSource.Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .Batch(false)
            .Read(read => 
                read.Action(    "Data_Read", 
                                "DataController", 
                                new { externalParentId = @ViewBag.externalParentId }))
            .Create(create => 
                create.Action(  "Data_Create", 
                                "DataController", 
                                new {   hidden_Id = @ViewBag.externalParentId , 
                                        externalParentId = @ViewBag.externalParentId }))
            .Update(update => 
                update.Action(  "Data_Update", 
                                "DataController", 
                                new { externalParentId = @ViewBag.externalParentId }))
            .Destroy(delete => 
                delete.Action(  "Data_Delete", 
                                "DataController", 
                                new { externalParentId = @ViewBag.externalParentId }))
            .Model(model => { 
                model.Id(m => m.Id); 
            })
    )
    .Pageable(pager => pager
        .Numeric(true)
        .PreviousNext(true)
        .PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 25, 50, 100 })
        .ButtonCount(5)
        .Messages(messages => messages.ItemsPerPage("Records / Page"))
    )
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Command(command => {
            command.Edit();
        }).Width(180);
        columns.Bound(m => m.Length).EditorTemplateName("Double");
        columns.Bound(m => m.Weight).EditorTemplateName("Double");
        columns.Bound(m => m.Sex).EditorTemplateName("Sex");
        columns.Bound(m => m.TagNumber)
            .HtmlAttributes("width: 100px;");
        columns.Command(command => {
            command.Destroy();
        }).Width(90);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;" })
    .ToolBar(tb => 
        tb.Create()
            .Text("Create")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "float-right submitposition" })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "margin: -43px 0px 0px 0px;" })
    )
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Name("DataDetails")
)
```

At this point, I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Comment: Are you getting any error in Browser Console?

Comment: Nope - no errors. I was actually surprised by that, as I figured it was some sort of error going on. But no. The console is clean.

Comment: Can you show your code for the "Double" EditorTemplate?

Comment: public GridBoundColumnBuilder<T> EditorTemplateName(string templateName);

It's not an EditorTemplate - it's an EditorTemplateName. It's part of the Kendo.Mvc.UI code, which is sadly too long to post here given the character length restrictions. You can find it in Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent, public class GridBoundColumnBuilder<T>.

Comment: I'll also add that removing the ".EditorTemplateName("Double")" from the columns doesn't have any effect. The issue still exists. I've also checked to see if this is a CSS thing by disabling all the active CSS styles (via Chrome's Dev Tools) - issue still persists.